# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'keras.objectives'

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, tf.keras

I am trying to run a file that is importing a package- `from keras.objectives import categorical_crossentropy`
Here it is saying *ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'keras.objectives'*

I found a similar question [here](https://github.com/theislab/dca/issues/48) but does not seems to be working.

How can I resolve this?

Comment: It's supposed to be keras.losses

Answer (score 0):

As mentionned in the link you posted you need to install the versions where this import exists.

```
pip install 'keras==2.4.3' 'tensorflow==2.4.0'
```

The imports works after that

```
>>> from keras.objectives import categorical_crossentropy
>>> categorical_crossentropy
<function categorical_crossentropy at 0x7f9665106ca0>
```

Comment: When i try to install these versions, I got the error: `ERROR: No matching distribution found for tensorflow==2.4.0`